# Can we compare two tables in a Switch Case in DAX Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, switch-statement, dax

Is it possible to include columns from 2 different tables in DAX Switch Function ?

Both of my tables are linked by Many to Many Relationship.
I am trying to create a calculated column in Table A where I want to compare Columns from Table B, but I can't add the Table B column in the DAX Switch formula. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
Pratik

Sample 
[Table B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SosU2.png) 
[Table A & Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaEIC.png)

Comment: What do you mean by compare two table, show some sample table and expected output

Comment: Hi @KinSiang,


I added the images to the question( Both Tables are already linked by ID). I am using Switch function in Table A to Compare the values in Table B. If the Values in Table B are 0 then the Comment in Table A for the same ID should be **Matched with B**. In my case I am just not able to compare the columns between the 2 tables. I hope I was clear, please let me know if you need any other info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it doesn't matter whether this table has many relationship, the only thing matter is that you are calculated based on your original table instead of calculate on a new measure, then result is unpredictable:

By create new table from the original table, and add column for the comment, I can provide result as your expectation, hope it solve your problem and accept the answer :)

1. Create new table from original table (Sheet1 is my old table) and select on `ID` column

   `Table = SELECTCOLUMNS(Sheet1,"ID",Sheet1[ID])`
2. Create new column for comment

   `Column = SWITCH(LOOKUPVALUE('Sheet1'[Value],Sheet1[ID],'Table'[ID]), 0,"Matched with A","Matched with B")`

The outcome for the new table:

[image]

Comment: Hi Kin,

Thanks for your reply. I am sorry, but I am still a little confused. 
In Switch function I can use the any column from the same table, but I am not able to use the column from a different table. I even tried to use Relate to get the column from Table B to Table A, but that is not working either. :(

Comment: I have checked `Switch` function, i think it is refer to the current row value, then compared it and return a value, work like `if` function, when you want to refer to value in other table, it is quite difficult to achieve one. But you can try `lookup` function to return a value then decide.

Comment: You can see my edited answer by referring to other table column and return the comment, accept the answer if helping, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, It can easily done with values from current table. My Client is trying to replicate something that he has done in Excel. But the mechanics work differently in Power BI. I will have to make him understand this and look for a different solution I guess. :P Thanks a lot for your help !!!!

Comment: I'll try the new solution and reply you back :)

Comment: Hi Kim, yes the Lookup solution is doing the trick. It works without creating the new table as well :) Thanks a lot !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to use two columns from two different tables for comparison in DAX, you can use the 'RELATED` DAX function to import a column from Table A to Table B or vice-versa. Then you can use this column for comparison in DAX.

Just set the appropriate relationship between Table A and Table B and create a new column with the `RELATED` DAX function to import the table that you want to use in the `SWITCH` function.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for the reply, but it's not working for me. 
The tables have an active link between them but I am getting the below error when I am using RELATED.

**The column 'ITC GL[Difference]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context.**

Do you have any idea why we get that error even when the tables are linked ?

Comment: Just to mention the relationship is Many to Many. Is it the cause of the error ?

Comment: Yes, can you make it One to One or Many to One and try again. It works for me. If you want I can update the answer with the proper relationship.

Comment: I have a 1 to many relationship so teh related function does not work. This seems to only work on 1 to 1